# Solution Design - Architecture : Auto-generate from and submit form events

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, architecture, auto-generate

This is a design issue i would like to discuses before starting development so , any opinion may help, there is no specific way to do it except that the system should be delivered under sharepoint  2010 and SP 2007 because of licensing issue.

My case as below

One user can define new service ( let say vacation request service), then he define the field with type ( let say Field1 (type:TextBox; DisplayName:employeeName) / field2 (Type:FileUpload;DisplayName:documentOne) then he define which users they can use ( from FBA asp membership users)

***this comes under (Dynamic Data Entry User Interfaces) .***

After the form is submitted , it will go throw normal approval process. with some common events and business rules.

what i am thinking to do :-

1) build  page that let you generate ASP.NET form ,

2) for each generate form , i create a list based on SharePoint list definition and by the event receiver i can set and remove users who can view / edit / add items using the SP Security module.

3) build my own D/B that saves each generate service what is the approval steps for it and any data i need to complete the approval workflow.

My Questions :-

***1) after i generate the form , how can i also write form events ( Submit event, onLoad event..etc), because each generated form will submit to different place to save data.

2) is this is the best practice to implement such system ?!

3) Should i save the form data in  SharePoint list or i should save it to DB also because i have two SharePoint environment and i may have performance issue while my data is separated between DB and SP. but in this case i need to implement my own security module.

4) we have around 200 from will be generated for phase one . so i am afraid that thing may get out of control if the design were not solid enough,

Comment: Not only am I having a hard time understand what you're asking, it's also clear that this is not the type of question well-suited for the Q/A format of SO

Comment: i re-write the question ,, hope its understandable now ..and what you mean by well-suited for the Q/A format of SO ?! i tagged architecture i though this will be enough ..

Answer (score 0):

1. submit everything to the same place with different parameters:

form table : (form filler id, form type id, form parameters id)
parameters table: (form id (Foreign Key), parameter id, parameter type, parameter text value)

this way its generic.

1. ?
2. save it in your database so that you would not be restricted to sharepoint structure.
3. do it lean - first build just a part of your solution and run it only on 1 or 2 forms. design the solution gradually rather then trying to predict everything from the beginning.